# Tabs are scrolling in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, tabs

In application i have six tabs. My problem is when i scrolls screen my tab also scrolls but i want tabview to be fixed. Tabs should always be visible.

Starting Screen is:----
[image: When i run my application screens look like this]
After scrolling is:-------
[image: Below button there is ads when i scrolls down tabs shifter above.]
Below share verse button i have displayed ads to view these tabs i need to scroll down. When i scroll down screen look like above image.
Any suggestion would be appericiated. Please let me know where i am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have now:

```
    MainScreen's default manager (with scroll)
    ---------------------
    | ----------------- |
    | |  TABS         | |
    | ----------------- |
    |                   |
    | ----------------- |
    | |  Other things | |
    | ----------------- |
    ---------------------
```

This is what it should look like:

```
    MainScreen's default manager (without scroll)
    ------------------------
    | -------------------- |
    | |     TABS         | |
    | -------------------- |
    |                      |
    |VerticalFieldManager  |
    | -------------------- |
    | |    Other things  | |
    | -------------------- |
    ------------------------
```

When you are adding things to a `MainScreen`, you are actually adding it to a `VerticalFieldManager` that is created behind the scenes in the screen constructor. This manager has scroll by default, but this can be customized in the `super` call:

```
    public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

        public MyScreen(){
            super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Now what you need to add to the screen is your tabs manager, and finally add every other field to a `VerticalFieldManager` with scroll.

Comment: One more thing,For creating tab i have used BitmapButtonField custom class that extends BaseButtonField. when i select first tab blue image changes to grey image. But when on same screen i click on arrow(in above image you can see), this is also BitmapButtonField, grey image changes to blue image(It looks no tab is selected). I want selected image to be in grey image. And one more prob is in above  image u can see grey link between tabs and other controls. I have not added anything. Please help me out.

Comment: Have a look at the [Advanced UI Library](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276). There's a `PillButtonSet` that does something similar. You could extend `ColoredPillButtonField` class to have a custom bg and a bitmap.

Comment: Yes in starting i implemented pillButtonSet but i hve to implement six tabs, they were not fitting in screen size.

Comment: I've done a similar thing and I'm able to display 5 tabs with bitmaps (but no text). The button width is defined by the button fields, not by the container.

Comment: can u please tell me how i can do this.If possible can you pls send me some code

Comment: I'm sorry, the code is propietary. But in short, you need to subclass `PillButtonField`, add a Bitmap variable, override `getPreferredWidth` and `getPreferredHeight` to return the w or h of the bitmap plus a padding, and finally override `paint` to draw the bitmap centered. I'm not sure going this way is shorter than making your own stateful button field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22802/discussion-between-soft-and-mister-smith)

Comment: @Thanks:- image i posted above has grey line. how i can remove this line. for fill this gap. pls help me out. And is there any other solution instead of implementing pillButtonField, right now on whatever control i click, tabs loses focus.

Comment: @soft Those lines are constants defined in `PillButtonField` class. What I did to hide them is to copy this class with a different name and convert the constants to protected attributes i can set to the same color as the background, so that they are not visible. You could edit the `paintBackground` method as well so that the lines are not painted. About an alternative, you could craft your own buttons but the difficult thing is to resize tab width dinamically when the number of tabs changes. `PillButtonField` gives me this out of the box.